# How to create ui alert view in .pch in objective c

Tags: iphone

```
#define kCustomAlert @"UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert Back" message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];[alert show];"
```

1. How to call this alert in view controller class?

Comment: This doesn't feel right. If you want a custom UIAlertView method thing then I'd create a category on UIAlertView that has a method to do this for you.

Comment: This is not the right way,How come you set up the alert delegates and this method wont help you in it anyways

Comment: @LithuT.V - `delegate` method would be call :) If you set it. I can explain you if you want.

Comment: @LithuT.V , i edited my code with delegate method example.

Comment: Everybody knows you are genius, no need to explain @PJR

Comment: See my answer below to see how to do this in 2018

Answer (score 7):

**Declare this macro in your pch file:**

```
 #define kCustomAlert() [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert Title" message:@"Alert Message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show]
```

**Macro Call:** kCustomAlert();

**Alert Macro With Parameter:**

```
#define kCustomAlertWithParam(title,msg) [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show]

kCustomAlertWithParam(@"This is Title",@"This is message");
```

**Alert Macro with Parameters and Target(For the use of: UIAlertView Delegate Methods)**

```
Please set UIAlertViewDelegate for your Controller.

#define kCustomAlertWithParamAndTarget(title,msg,target) [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:target cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show]

kCustomAlertWithParamAndTarget(@"This is Title",@"This is message",self);
```

Comment: What are you doing @PJR, Just copying my answer here ?

Comment: Hey @TheTiger , i have not any idea about your answer , i was trying macro in my  mac after reading a question and then answered it.

Comment: Great!! You have answered 10 minutes ago and my answer is 7 minutes older than you ... didn't you see it ? And dic2 .. Anyways .... NP

Comment: OMG..I have not any idea.. i did not see it and if you hurt i feel sorry for that :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a **macro** function You can't define it like so. Your Syntax is wrong.
Do it in this way:

```
#define ShowAlert() [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show]
```

And call it like:

```
ShowAlert();
```

**You can also pass the parameters:-**

```
#define ShowAlert(myTitle, myMessage) [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:myTitle message:myMessage delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show]
```

And call it like:

```
ShowAlert(@"YourTitle", @"YourMessage");
```

**Note: I'm not saying that this is good to use just telling the way to do so.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to achieve this or is it possible even or not but the alternative for this is to use below method in your AppDelegate.m and declare the method in AppDelegate.h file and then you can call it by creating AppDelegate instance in any class

```
-(void)showAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a old question, but as `UIAlertView` is now deprecated, the answers provided will generate a warning.

Here's how you can achieve this with `UIAlertViewController` :

**FROM A VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
#define ShowAlert(title, myMessage)  { UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:myMessage preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert]; [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]]; [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil]; }
```

Note that this one can only be used in a view controller.

---

**FROM ANYWHERE**

If you want to be able to show an alert anywhere, you'll need this one :

```
#define ShowAlertFromTopMostController(title, myMessage)  { UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:myMessage preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert]; [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]]; [[Utils topMostController] presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil]; }
```

and you'll need to add following method to a `Utils` class (subclassing `NSObject`) :

```
+(UIViewController*) topMostController {
    UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    while (topController.presentedViewController) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController;
    }

    return topController;
}
```